# HTML and JavaScript Proof Writer

Tags: javascript, html

all, I asked a question about this program earlier, but I have a new problem. I'm trying to make a two-column proof writer, and I'm having trouble with some of the code. It's relatively simple stuff, but for some reason, nothing I have been trying has been working. The code is as follows:

```
<HTML>
<body>
<font size="5">
<p align="center">
<p1>Insert Given:</p1>
<div align="center"; id="Input1">
    <form id='user-input'>
        <input type='text' id='given' placeholder='Given Information'></input>
    </form>
<p2>Insert Statement<br>to Prove:</p2>
<br>
<div align="center"; id="Input2">
    <form id='user-input'>
        <input type='text' id='prove' placeholder='Statement to Prove'></input>
    </form>
<button id='Submit' Value='Edit' onClick="edit()">Submit</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
  function edit()
{
       var x = document.getElementById('given').value;
       var y = document.getElementById('prove').value;
       print x;
}

</script>
<br>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table style="width:100%">
<col Width="15">
<col Width="300">
<col Width="500">
  <tr>
    <th>Step Number</th>
    <th>Step</th>       
    <th>Explaination</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><var="x"></var></td>        
    <td>Given</td>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want this to do a few things that it currently refuses to do. Firstly, I just want the onclick function edit() to show the value of x so that I can make sure that it is accepting the user's input. The other thing that I'm annoyed at is that I can't find a way to print this variable in the HTML based table below the function. If the user says for the given something like (Angle ABD is Bisected by Ray BC), for example, I want that to be displayed in the first row as the given statement and then I will work from there getting the code to check different postulates, theorems, etc. until the desired proof is created based off the user input of "Statement to Prove"

Sorry for my messy code and inexperience, I'm only a freshman in HS, so I haven't worked with JavaScript and HTML for terribly long.

I intend to do some "if...then" statements for the properties and postulates and such, saying for example if "previous step" is a statement of congruency (I'll check for formatting words) and "statement to prove" is a statement of equality, then (br or however you extend the table, (a) = (b) instead of (a) =~ (b)). If you know a better way of adapting this system that will save me a lot of time I'd be more than happy to take some tips.

Comment: For outputting your data into the table (AKA "DOM manipulation"), you better use jquery. It will make code shorter and easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your 'print x' with 'console.log(x)' because I don't think print is a valid JS statement.

For outputting the data into your table, your probably looking at something like '.innerHTML'. To use that you would have to 'find' your DOM element (probably by giving it an ID) using 'document.getElementById('id')' then use '.innerHTML' on that to write stuff to the table.

Comment: I'm still a little confused on how to call the JS in the HTML table. If I enter document.getElementByID("Input1").innerHTML to the table it wont take it because it is a JS command not an HTML one.

Comment: Oh, sorry if I wasn't clear. I meant that you use that code in your javascript TO write stuff to your HTML (it isn't going to work in the HTML, it IS javascript code. Also, you would have to give an ID to the actual row you want to write it to, not the whole table.

Comment: So would I add id="Whatever" to the <td> tag and then in the JS function say like document.getElementById('Whatever').innerHTML?

Comment: Or do I say in the JS function: document.getElementById('The <td>'s id').innerHTML.value='x'?

Comment: I'm going to assume you want to put the 'x' value you get given, and put that into the <td> that is above '<td>Given</td>' and below '<td>1</td>':

The HTML:

Change <td><var='x'></var></td> to <td id='givenValue'></td>

Then in your JS (at the end of it) add:

document.getElementById("givenValue").innerHTML = x;